# October CMS Invalid security token after login in Backend

Tags: php, content-management-system, octobercms

I upload a project October CMS in another Host, and after login in Backend, returns Invalid security token

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Octobercms2, try to set 'enable_csrf_protection' to 'false' in config/system.php